# How do I make a custom button shape with custom lines

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I'm trying to create a custom button in WPF and I'm running into an issue. I don't want the button to highlight unless I'm inside the visible lines with my cursor.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<Button Width="100"
        Height="25"
        Background="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="0">
    <Viewbox  Stretch="Uniform">
        <Canvas Name="svg" Width="373.000000" Height="58.000000">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Canvas.Resources/>
            <Canvas Name="g24">
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.100000" ScaleY="-0.100000"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="0.000000" Y="58.000000"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <Path Name="path" Fill="#FF000000">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M0 390 l0 -180 138 0 137 0 100 -100 100 -100 1375 0 1375 0 100 100 100 100 147 0 148 0 0 180 0 180 -1860 0 -1860 0 0 -180z m3700 0 l0 -150 -143 0 -142 0 -105 -105 -105 -105 -1350 0 -1350 0 -100 100 -100 100 -137 0 -138 0 0 155 0 155 1835 0 1835 0 0 -150z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

Comment: The default style for `Button` has a `ControlTemplate` that applies a highlight style on a `IsMouseOver` property trigger. You can define your own modified version of that `ControlTemplate` to remove the highlight or only highlight when `IsMouseOver` is true for your Path element

Comment: Do you intend the button to be the shape of your geometry? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29866.aspx